# How set default app preferences for KDE apps on Ubuntu?

Tags: kde, default-programs, thunar

I use kfind on Ubuntu. I need to set the default apps it uses to launch files it finds.

By default, it attempts to launch kde apps. I usually either don't have them, or don't want to use them.

I most especially want it to launch Thunar when I click 'open parent folder' on a search result.

But I cannot see where to do this. I installed 'systemsettings', the kde config app. But that seems to have no option to set default apps. I looked in ~/.kde/share/apps/ and ~/.kde/share/config, but could find no config setting. I can't see any version of kconfig or kcontrol to install.

So how do I change this setting for KDE apps in Ubuntu?

UPDATE:

In answer to Michael Clare (thank you), xdg-mime thinks my default is Thunar. And indeed it is. But not for any KDE app.

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
Thunar-folder-handler.desktop
```

Comment: Can't catfish accomplish what your trying to do? Since it's a gtk app you shouldn't have any issues running your default apps.

Comment: I've been using kfind for years because it was so much better than anything else available to me, including catfish. I checked on intervals. And no longer bother checking. I use kfind.

Comment: Have you tried "xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory" as a regular user?

Comment: When you click "Open containing folder", Kfind invokes `KIO::highlightInFileManager`, which in turn invokes the FileManager1 DBus interface. I _think_ it should suffice to save the contents of [this file](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/thunar/blob/master/org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service.in) as `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service `. However, that dbus interface seems to be very finicky. See [this KDE bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=397953) for more information.

Comment: thank you , danzel. I'll have a look at this bug report.... FYI. I have /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Thunar.service, with Name=org.xfce.Thunar and Exec=/usr/bin/Thunar --daemon

Comment: Michael Clare  - please post your comment as an answer so I can give it full credit as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

$ xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory

Solves the problem. As Michael helpfully posted in comments.